# customer save before process checkout button click

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, onepage-checkout

Hello I want to save new customer on checkout page after filling their information but before process to checkout button clicked. Is their any possibility to save new customer using this method?

Comment: The observer us not working for me. Mag1.7. To have payment methods defined by customer group, having a guest turn into a logged user and having more payment methods offered is my goal, am I in the correct path?
Any advice.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

write an observer to get triggered on save billing or save shipping events and save the customer.

for example:

> create Yournamespace_Yourmodulename.xml in app/etc/modules/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Yournamespace_Yourmodulename>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Yournamespace_Yourmodulename>
</modules>
```

> in app/code/local/Yournamespace/Yourmodulename/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Yournamespace_Yourmodulename>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Yournamespace_Yourmodulename>
</modules>
<global>
    <events>
        <controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling>
            <observers>
                <auto_register_shipping>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Yournamespace_Yourmodulename_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>autoRegisterBilling</method>
                </auto_register_shipping>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling>
    </events>
</global>
</config>
```

> in app/code/local/Yournamespace/Yourmodulename/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php
class Yournamespace_Yourmodulename_Model_Observer {

    public function autoRegisterBilling($evt){
        if(!Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()){
            $data = $evt->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getRequest()->getPost('billing', array());
            $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
            $email = $data['email'];
            $websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
            $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
            $pwd = $data['customer_password'];
            $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())->loadByEmail($email);

            if (!$customer->getId()) {
                 //Code begins here for new customer registration
                $customer->website_id = $websiteId;
                $customer->setStore($store);
                $customer->firstname = $data['firstname'];
                $customer->lastname = $data['lastname'];
                $customer->setEmail($email);
                $customer->setPassword($pwd);
                $customer->sendNewAccountEmail('confirmed');  
                $customer->save();
                   }
           }
    }
}
```

**note :**

1. this will save a customer immediately after they click continue in billing information tab.
2. you can do this on save shipping or save payment method steps.
3. if you wanna automatically login that customer, add the following in Observer.php after

   ```
   $customer->save();
   }

   Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginById($customer->getId()); // to login that customer.
   ```

Comment: i want add observer on save payment method then?

Comment: it is not working in save billing means observer not calling

Comment: just check  whether "autoRegisterBilling()" is executed.

Comment: it is calling but getting NULL values only getting POST CODE

Comment: i am using one page checkout

Comment: are you using >$data = $evt->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getRequest()->getPost('billing', array()); in observer.php for savePayment event?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9894/discussion-between-shathish-and-keyur-shah)

Comment: #3 - If I want the page to refresh and reflect the customer is actually logged in (right now the header remains the same) how would I do that?

Comment: @kevando: that sounds like a good question, why don't you post it as a separate question? Something like "how to update toplinks from observer in checkout page?"

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for that great solution. I was looking for that from long time.
But I've juste an important a notice regarding your note 3 "auto login".
If you add the following line...

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginById($customer->getId());
```

...outside the following condition:

```
if (!$customer->getId()) {
```

It will result that if you entered an existing email address, you'll be automatically logged with the related account.
Do you have the same result from your side?

By the way, I've juste moved the "auto login" instruction Inside the conditon. And it work just like a charm.